# URL Redirection from a html page to an .aspx page

Tags: asp.net, html, iis, web, isapi-redirect

I have a requirement where i have to use url redirection in my legacy web page (basically its a complete static html page).

The requirement for me is to redirect the user everytime, from the static html page to a .aspx page

i.e if my earlier page were found to be at

```
http://web.vatsag.com/app/en/downloadsite.htm
```

then i have to redirect to the following page (.aspx)

```
http://web.vatsag.com/app/newdownloadsite.aspx
```

I went through the following links, which talks mainly redirection w.r.t ASP.NET

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2538/URL-Rewriting-with-ASP-NET

However,

Since the pages are html. I presume by default not handled by the ASP.NET ISAPI filter

Can anyone help me in achieving the same using any of the alternatives specified below ?

1. Any particular setting that could be done on the IIS Side
2. Programmatically achieving redirection using Meta Refresh (although i have heard this method is highly discouraged)

Thanks in advance

VATSAG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different options of doing so described [here](http://www.webworkshop.net/auto-redirecting_methods.html). You can basically add a meta tag to refresh the page after a second to aspx page or use javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers Prashant, I took the javascript option for achieving the redirection;

Comment: Any ideas how do i query the url parameters and redirect the same ?

Comment: look at lots of options here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values

Answer (score 1):

between the head tags, put this code.

```
<head>       
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;URL='http://web.vatsag.com/app/newdownloadsite.aspx'" />    
  </head>
```

That will redirect after 2 seconds to http://web.vatsag.com/app/newdownloadsite.aspx

Content= Number of seconds to refresh
URL = url path to redirect to
The reason meta refreshes are discouraged is because spammers use them to redirect users from shell sites that have lots of keywords to non-legitimate sites. So search engines blacklist sites that use that meta refresh as belonging to spammers.

Comment: +1, :) for explaining the reason behind why HTML standards organization discourage the use of meta-refresh inside the pages

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.helicontech.com/download-isapi_rewrite3.htm) and let the IIS server redirect your .html page. Use the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^app/en/downloadsite.htm$ /app/newdownloadsite.aspx [NC,R=301,L]
```