# Will changing file extension affect SE rankings?

Tags: html, asp-classic, seo, search-engine, google-ranking

I'm updating a site and changing the pages from .html to .asp the pages will have the exact same name as the old html pages the only difference will be the file extension. Will this affect existing SE rankings? is there a solution? I'm on a Microsoft server no Apache for me here. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes, because a new extension makes the URL a new URL. All links and rankings your current page has will be lost.
2. No, because you can do a 301 redirect from the old URL to the URL will tells the search engines your page has moved and where it has moved to. All links and rankings will (eventually) be restored to the new page.

Comment: Thanks! Doing a 301 redirect will be then.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will. You need a use a 301 redirect on the original page and point to the new page in order to carry-over any SEO value.

See: http://www.hochmanconsultants.com/articles/301-versus-302.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to automatically serve .asp pages when someone requests a .html.

In IIS this can be done using URL Rewriting, please see the following for a quick guide.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx
This way you won’t need to worry about google etc as that can carry on requesting html and will be given the correct page regardless (without a redirect).
For a more classic asp solution (the link above is a bit .net specific) you can make use of the many ISAPI Rewrite modules, for example: [isapi_rewrite](http://www.isapirewrite.com/) which lets you do stuff like this:

```
<rule name="RewriteHTMLtoASP" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*).html(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.asp{R:2}" />
</rule>
```

I'm sure there are free solutions out there too, i just dont know any off the top of my head.

Similar question: [URL Redirection from a html page to an .aspx page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068519/url-redirection-from-a-html-page-to-an-aspx-page)

Comment: Thanks, for now I went with the 301 redirects, but I will def. keep this in mind for next time.